# How do I resolve Unexpected character '' error when precompiling assets in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am trying to deploy my app for the first time and running into problems with the asset pipeline. When I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I get the following error;

```
cool_app@ip-10-248-17-168:/rails_apps/cool_app/current$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/home/cool_app/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby /rails_apps/cool_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Unexpected character '' (line: 13934, col: 1, pos: 403510)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:1720:22)
    at js_error (<eval>:1728:15)
    at parse_error (<eval>:1824:17)
    at next_token (<eval>:2070:17)
    at handle_slash (<eval>:2024:32)
    at Object.next_token [as input] (<eval>:2067:39)
    at next (<eval>:2175:37)
    at Object.semicolon [as 1] (<eval>:2221:38)
    at prog1 (<eval>:2770:28)
    at simple_statement (<eval>:2362:35)
  (in /rails_apps/cool_app/releases/20121128034720/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
```

I presume that this means I have an illegal character (that's not rendering) somewhere in my maze of javascript (should have deployed earlier!) but telling me it's at column 1 on line 13934 doesn't seem to be particularly useful. How do I go about hunting this down? The error message is spectacularly unhelpful (and I notice a lot of other questions on this theme here too).

- Edit -

I'm not sure of the significance, but if I run `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile` on my development machine, the task seems to execute without complaint. My Server is Ubuntu 12.04 and my dev machine in OSX 10.8. I don't know enough about Javascript runtimes to solve this myself right now (but I'm hunting).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hokay,

My head hurts from the hours of bashing it against my keyboard but I solved my problem.

First, some reading around suggested that uglifier was the cause of my error. I set `config.assets.compress = false` in config/production.rb and sure enough I was able to precompile my assets.

I wasn't happy with this though as my Javascript file was 625kB and I really wanted it compressed, so I looked in the generated application.js file and found what line 13934, column 1 referred to. Turns out it was line 8, column 1 of the file jquery.caret.1.02.js, a small jQuery plugin I am using. This first line looks like so;

```
 (function($,len,createRange,duplicate){
```

with a space in front of the line. I deleted that space (I suspect it is some incorrect non-printing unicode character but haven't bothered looking into it), set `config.assets.compress = true`, and tried again and no more error message! (and my Javascript is down to 159kB)

I hope that this helps someone one day.

Answer (score 1):

another reason might be html-style comments in your js files.

this will produce

```
Unexpected character '<'
```

just to bring it out there, hope it saves someone some time and trouble

Answer (score 1):

I've been bashing my head on this problem for a while as well. For me, the issue was in using the gem **uglifier**. When I removed uglifier and ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` again, I was successful.

It seems to a javascript compression issue, generally speaking. See what gems you are using to compress your JS

Comment: Yes, by setting config.assets.compress = false I disabled uglifier. Unfortunately it leaves you with large javascript files which may or may not be a problem. You should try to find the code that is making uglifier choke and correct it.